# Import a script in another in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `contactus.js` in whitch is defined the `sendMail(to)` function.

I have `main.js`:

```
...

$('#ContactUs').click(function(){
  // how to execute /contactus.js, and when done, send mail? 
  sendMail(to);
});

...
```

However, as `main.js` is used in every HTML page of the site, I didn't like to include `contactus.js` before `main.js`, in order do not load a useless script.

I need to load (execute) contactus.js only when a click on the #contactus was made.

EDIT:

I added a Fiddle here, to demonstrate the effect:

```js
$(function() {
  console.log("ready!");
  
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    console.log("click start");
    
    $.getScript("http://parsleyjs.org/dist/parsley.js", function() {
      console.log("the object is: " + window.parsley);
    });
    
    console.log("click end");
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="alert('done');" id="myForm">
  <input type="email" required>
  <div id="submit">submit</div>
</form>
```

I expect "window.parsley" be defined, but is not...

Comment: odle, if you put in the status code etc, it claims to be successfull. `$.getScript("http://parsleyjs.org/dist/parsley.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) { console.log(data, textStatus, jqxhr.status); });` this lib has the require shim in it, could be a cause (`data` is empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/), like below.

> Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

```
$('#ContactUs').click(function(){
  // how to execute /contactus.js, and when done, send mail? 
    $.getScript("/contactus.js", function() {    
        sendMail(to);
    });
});
```

Comment: This should work as long as the JS is available in the specified path and `sendMail` has no errors! But, if there are errors elsewhere, they need to be looked at. A look at the browser console would be a good start.

Comment: added a fiddle in the question: I expect "window.parsley" be defined, but is not..

Comment: @serhio you need to pay close attention to variables as it's `window.Parsley` and not `window.parsley` (notice the case!) Take a [look here](http://jsfiddle.net/7pxpryf4/)

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

**Or** add `<script>` tag dynamically,

```
$('#ContactUs').click(function(){
   var src = navigator.appName == "contactus.js";    
    var regScript = document.createElement("script");
    regScript.setAttribute("src", src);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  sendMail(to);
});
```

Hope it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jQuery.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) like this:

```
$('#ContactUs').click(function(){
  $.getScript('/path/to/contactus.js', function() { 
    sendMail(to);
  });
});
```

Comment: what exactly does this "getScript". Loads in memory the JS, or executes it?

Comment: @serhio it basically inserts `script` tag with the src attribute specified. So yes, it executes it. So if your function `sendMail` is in the global scope of that script, it should be available inside the callback.

Comment: added a fiddle to better demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume then you'd want to inject the script into the head. like:

```
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = " /contactus.js";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

This can also be achieve in jquery using `$.getScript` ([see docs here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/))

Having said that, if the script is only small and used for the contact form, loading it along all the html pages might be the better option.

The script would be cached, but the place where it's used (on click) would be more responsive as you wont be waiting for the script to load

Comment: added a fiddle to better demonstrate the problem